# Plotting variable data in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My code below allows user to look up stock returns based on sector/subindustry/etc.

```
sector='XLF'
subindustry='Insurance Brokers'
tickers = ['']
benchmark = ['^OEX']

stocks = tickers + benchmark + sector + subindustry
```

This compiles into a df where stock returns is calculated:

```
stock_return = dataFrame.pct_change()
```

What I want is a plt.plot that shows only the lines where data was entered. e.g. if someone enters just the sector 'XLF' and benchmark - I want just those two plotted. As of now if I do that I get an error saying KeyError: "['Average' 'Sector' 'Sub-industry'] not in index"

```
stocks_sorted = {'T': tickers,
     'B': benchmark,
     'S': sector,
     'Sub': subindustry}


def average_data(stocks):
    for stock in stocks:
        if len(stocks_sorted['T']) >= 2:
            stock_return['Average'] = stock_return[tickers].apply(np.mean,axis=1)
        if len(stocks_sorted['Sub']) >=2:
            stock_return['Sub-industry'] = stock_return[subindustry].apply(np.mean,axis=1)
        if len(stocks_sorted['S']) >= 2:
            stock_return['Sector'] = stock_return[sector].apply(np.mean,axis=1) 
    return stock_return

plt.plot(stock_return[['Average','^OEX','Sector','Sub-industry']]*100)
```

My expected output is to plot ONLY the columns where data is actually given, and ignore the other ones (vice versa for other scenarios). Thanks

Comment: I found a cheap way of doing it and that's going "else: 
            excess_move['Average']==0" for every if line ... wondering if anyone has another way?

Comment: Can you post a picture of how it looks now?

Comment: the yahoo fin API is bugging on me - but basically just a plot with benchmark/sector (the ones I put values in for) , and the empty ones are represented as a line on x=0 with y=0 . Ideally I wouldnt have those extra lines there

Comment: If your method works and no one comes in here with a better one, I say post/accept your answer